# Convert each corresponding elements of arrays to vector in r

Tags: arrays, r

I have a large number of arrays and would like to covert all element at specific position in all these arrays in a vector. That is, if I have 2 arryas as follows:

```
, , 39

            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]     [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.0000000 0.000000    0
[2,]  0.06703875  0.00000000  0.0000000 0.000000    0
[3,]  0.60078853  0.48239226  0.0000000 0.000000    0
[4,] -0.41071928 -0.03397696 -1.3588026 0.000000    0
[5,] -0.27326482  0.84172740 -0.3139296 1.515104    0

, , 40

            [,1]       [,2]      [,3]    [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.000000000  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000    0
[2,] 0.003862625  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000    0
[3,] 0.187788593 -0.1087561 0.0000000 0.00000    0
[4,] 0.186767234  0.2369021 0.2967447 0.00000    0
[5,] 1.008507457  0.7118111 0.1412379 1.02506    0
```

Then I would like to have 10 vectors as follows (only the values at lower triangular):

```
v1( 0.06703875 ,  0.003862625 ) 
v2(0.60078853  ,  0.187788593 )
       .  .  .
       .  .  .
v10(1.515104 , 1.02506)
```

so all the element which are at the same position will be stored into a vector. 
I have 300 hundred such these arrays and would like to do it automatically in R. Any idea and help please?

Comment: Please use `dput` to post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` to subset to the lower triangle, but it will simplify its result to a matrix (which may actually be a better data structure). To split that matrix into vectors, you can use `split` with a sequence of the number of rows, which will recycle as you want because matrices subset column-wise (as they fill) if you only supply one index. All together:

```r
set.seed(47)

a <- array(rnorm(5 * 5 * 2), c(5, 5, 2))

lower_tris <- apply(a, 3, function(x){x[lower.tri(x)]}) 

list_of_pairs <- split(lower_tris, seq(nrow(lower_tris)))
# or with @lmo's cleaner approach,
# list_of_pairs <- split(lower_tris, row(lower_tris))

str(list_of_pairs)
#> List of 10
#>  $ 1 : num [1:2] 0.711 -1.608
#>  $ 2 : num [1:2] 0.185 -2.322
#>  $ 3 : num [1:2] -0.282 -1.967
#>  $ 4 : num [1:2] 0.1088 0.0275
#>  $ 5 : num [1:2] 0.0151 -1.2004
#>  $ 6 : num [1:2] -0.252 0.885
#>  $ 7 : num [1:2] -1.466 0.887
#>  $ 8 : num [1:2] -1.828 0.507
#>  $ 9 : num [1:2] 0.0915 0.5643
#>  $ 10: num [1:2] -0.0406 -0.4877
```

`split` automatically names each element by the splitting factor; wrap the call in `unname` if you like.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using `aperm` and logical subsetting is

```
# Use array provided in alistaire's answer, modified to set the upper triangle to 0
set.seed(47)
a <- array(rnorm(5 * 5 * 2), c(5, 5, 2))
for(i in 1:2) a[,,i][upper.tri(a[,,i], diag = TRUE)] <- 0
```

---

With this array, use `aperm` to sort the data so the third dimensional elements are in a column

```
tmp <- aperm(a, c(3, 2, 1))
```

Now, extract non-zero elements and put them in a matrix:

```
myMat <- matrix(tmp[tmp != 0], 2)
```

---

If you want a list use `split`:

```
split(myMat, col(myMat))
$`1`
[1]  0.7111425 -1.6081599

$`2`
[1]  0.1854053 -2.3223723

$`3`
[1]  0.01513086 -1.20044063

...
```

Answer (score 0):

See the comperes package and the function mat_to_long():

```
library(comperes)
long.dat <- mat_to_long(matrix, "row", "col", "val")
```