# Error in apply(a, 3, function(x) { : dim(X) must have a positive length, apply does not work with list

Tags: r

I tried to convert the array to `lower.tri` matrices and then convert it to a vector where all elements in the same positon will be joined in one vector. The code worked very good without using the list. However, it does not work if I applied it to a list! Where is the problem? any help please? (note, the code is one of answer of one of my question ([old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959054/convert-each-corresponding-elements-of-arrays-to-vector-in-r))

```
set.seed(47)
a <- list()  ## if a is not a list then it works very good. 
for( i in 1:2){

a[[i]] <- array(rnorm(5 * 5 * 2), c(5, 5, 2))

lower_tris <- apply(a[[i]], 3, function(x){x[lower.tri(x)]}) 

list_of_pairs <- split(lower_tris, seq(nrow(lower_tris)))
}
```

Comment: Did you meant `lower_tris <- apply(a[[i]], 3, function(x){x[lower.tri(x)]})`

Comment: yes. That does not work

Comment: You need to have `lower_tris` also as a `list`

Comment: why we need to save it as a list while `apply` already applied to list

Comment: Thanks so much @akrun. Your help always great.

Comment: `apply(a[[i]], 3, ..` is looping through the array within each `list` element 'i'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason would be that `a` is a `list` of arrays, and we need to pass through the `list` of `arrays` with `a[[i]]`.  Similarly, create the output `list` as the same `length` of 'a' and then assign the output from each iteration to the `i`th `list` element

```
a <- vector('list', 2)
lower_tris <- vector('list', 2)
list_of_pairs <- vector('list', 2)

set.seed(47)
for( i in seq_along(a)){       
   a[[i]] <- array(rnorm(5 * 5 * 2), c(5, 5, 2))
   lower_tris[[i]] <- apply(a[[i]], 3, function(x){x[lower.tri(x)]}) 
   list_of_pairs[[i]] <- split(lower_tris[[i]], seq(nrow(lower_tris[[i]])))
 }
```

---

If we are using `lapply`, then we can directly use the same code as in the OP's post

```
set.seed(47)
out <- lapply(1:2, function(i) {          
         a <- array(rnorm(5 * 5 * 2), c(5, 5, 2))
         lower_tris <- apply(a, 3, function(x) x[lower.tri(x)])
         split(lower_tris, seq(nrow(lower_tris))) })

identical(list_of_pairs, out)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks so much. However, is there a different between `vector('list', 2)` and `list`

Comment: @Alice  With `vector('list', 2)`, we are predefining the `length`.  Simply calling `list` will be a `list` of `length` 0 and it would get appended as we iterate.  But, I think predefining the length should be faster

Comment: I will apply it to my very complex function and see. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Alice, you can use `lapply` and then your code should work fine, but then the output will be only the `split`, or otherwise, we have to return a `list`